How can I find out when the running Firefox session was started on Linux?
How can I find out when the current/running Firefox session was started on Linux?
With time and date info.
Which command in the terminal should I use?

Which linux distro are you using, and which shell?

man ps should tell you how to find that info. I tend to use ps awxk start_time -O ppid,user,%cpu,%mem,trs:7,vsz:7,rsz:7,drs:7,stat,class,lstart,ni. Not sure what distro & shell have to do with it.

linux mint with bash.

That info needs to be in the main question. When asked for further, clearly relevant information, please always add that to the main question by Editing it.

If the use of the terminal is not a requirement, you can ask Firefox to tell you when it was launched.
Enable the command line of the Browser Console (not to be confused with Web Console).
Then pass to it the following line
Date(JSON.parse(SessionStore.getBrowserState()).session.startTime);

There you have it. I think for all practical purposes it is good enough. And of course this method is OS agnostic, so accepted everywhere.
